# Transfer or Collect an nft via smart contract

Tags: wallets, transfer, nft, blockchain

I would like to be able via my smart contract that a user can buy(collect) and transfer an nft. And that the nft passes from one wallet to another.

For the moment everything is working well, I mint a nft well I see it in my Temple wallet in "collectibles".
https://legacy.smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmTCo3K5sTk7rxsxjqXoGVhD5UZW3XVZTKahHVfRgquHxR&k=f26cd4844ff1f7811e4a

But the problem is that when I want to transfer or buy this nft via my smart contract, the modification change the marketplace but not the token. The token in question is still on my wallet and not on the wallet of my target (of the buyer or of the destination of the transfer)

Here is my code in react js:
[image: react js code]